# How to scan maven plugin dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

In my project I attached commons-lang3 to plugin and commons-io to project:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>@project.groupId@</groupId>
            <artifactId>@project.artifactId@</artifactId>
            <version>@project.version@</version>
               (...)
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Within my custom plugin (within my mojo), I can find commons-io

```
@Component
private MavenProject project;
(...)
project.getDependecies(); // [{groupId=commons-io, artifactId=commons-io...
```

How to find commons-lang3?

Comment: run `mvn help:effective-pom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Maven API, from the MavenProject you can get the Build instance and from it then the list of configured plugins, from each Plugin object you can then have its dependencies as following:

```
@Component
private PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor;
(...)

List<Plugin> plugins = project.getBuild().getPlugins();
for (Plugin p : plugins) {
    if (p.getId().equals(pluginDescriptor.getId())) {
       List<Dependency> pluginDependencies = p.getDependencies();
       // your logic here
       break;
    }
}
```

If you really want to cover every case, you can also scan the plugins configured in the currently active profiles as following:

```
List<Profile> profiles = project.getActiveProfiles();
for (Profile p : profiles) {
   // from personal experience, don't forget this check!
   if (p.getBuild() != null) {
        checkAsShownAbove(p.getBuild().getPlugins());
   }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As commons-lang3 is declared as a dependency only for a specific plugin, it is not available during compilation. You have to explicitly define commons-lang3 as a dependency (if its not getting included as a transitive dependency) similar to how you have defined commons-io.

Comment: However, maven compiler plugin allows supports non-standard compilers. These compilers are defined as plugin dependency and they are "working". I want implement something similar. I will update description to be more clear